# Facing Problem with Description in Post and Home Page in Wordpress

Tags: seo, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

Recently I've configured SEO by Yoast for better On-page. But, after analyzing the SEO score and different aspects of it I found out that the template is considering 
General > **Tagline** as the Meta Description for the Home Page (I'm using Custom Page as an Home Page).

And for Post Template is considering **initial line as the meta description** for the post. How to fix this problem I've already tried contacting SEO Yoast support and template support but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, do not worry too much about Meta Descriptions too much. Search engines decides to show their own bits of meta description, based on Keyword Searches.

Make sure your content is perfected & is relevant.

Having said that, make sure:

- You go `Custom Page > Yoast SEO options > Meta Description` & add
  your meta description for the page.
- Go to `Dashboard > SEO > Titles & Metas > General` & ensure Force
      Rewrite Titles is checked.
- Do not write any Meta Description for Post Template. Instead, add
  meta description from the Post Edit screen.

Comment: You go Custom Page > Yoast SEO options > Meta Description & add your meta description for the page.
Already Did.

All 3 steps checked. Can you verify that the issue has been resolved ?

Comment: The Meta Description is still not updated